# How do I do a REGEXP on all the columns in a table?

Tags: mysql

**How do I do a REGEXP on all the columns?**

This is my table:

```
mysql> select * from datatables_demo;
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name | position    | office | start_date | salary |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Tiger      | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
|  2 | Garrett    | Winters   | Accountant2 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 170750 |
|  3 | Ashton     | Cox       | Accountant3 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 |  86000 |
|  4 | Cedric     | Kelly     | Accountant4 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 433060 |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is how I select all columns and do a REGEXP on 1 column `first_name`:

```
mysql> select * from datatables_demo WHERE first_name REGEXP 'T';
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
| id | first_name | last_name | position    | office | start_date | salary |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Tiger      | Nixon     | Accountant  | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 320800 |
|  2 | Garrett    | Winters   | Accountant2 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 | 170750 |
|  3 | Ashton     | Cox       | Accountant3 | Tokyo  | 2016-11-08 |  86000 |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------+--------+------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**How do I do a REGEXP on all the columns?** This is my attempt but its not right.

```
mysql> select * from datatables_demo WHERE * REGEXP 'T';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* REGEXP 'T'' at line 1
mysql>
```

could not work it out from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Do I have to write out a REGEXP per column:
`select * from datatables_demo WHERE column1 REGEXP 'T' OR column2 REGEXP 'T' OR columnN REGEXP 'T';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either write it per column or use concat prior to regexp it. please reveiew this one:

```
SELECT * FROM datatables_demo where CONCAT(first_name, last_name, position, office) REGEXP 'T';
```

Comment: tks, think that's what I am looking for.

Comment: @HattrickNZ Note that this will return rows where the regexp matches across different columns. So if the regexp is `sj`, it will match `first_name = james` and `last_name = jones` because the concatenation creates `jamesjones`. It probably would be better to use `CONCAT_WS()` to put a delimiter between each column.